# Sencha losing context

Tags: extjs, scope, bind

I am trying to call a generic function but when that function is executed I am in a different scope (window). This code will picture the case:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    context: null,

    function1 : function(){
        this.function2(this.function3);
    },

    function2 : function(func){
        func();
    },

    function3 : function(){
        if(context == this){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Same context!');
        }
        else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Different context!');
        }
    },

    launch : function() {
        context = this;
        this.function1();
    }
});
```

I am trying to use bind but it is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind`, try changing `function1`, like:

```
function1: function(){
    this.function2(this.function3.bind(this));
}
```

(This way `func` in `function2` is a new function with your expected `this`.)